# MongoDB Shard Transaction Aborted caused by cluster data placement change

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB Abort Transaction with the following error:

> 10-06T03:37:40.960-0400 I COMMAND [conn502] command DB.CollectioName command: delete { delete: "AwsBillingDaily_1", ordered: true, $db: "BESPIN", $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1570347453, 2), signature:
>   { hash: BinData(0, 032AB6CDE1FE06D1DD41E2663F3D2A3A499FA5C3), keyId: 6743826200705105950 }
>   }, lsid: { id: UUID("86b989ac-2603-4b11-8a8d-bcd2157b1309") }, txnNumber: 1, startTransaction: true, readConcern: { level: "local" }, autocommit: false } numYields:0 ok:0 errMsg:"Transaction 86b989ac-2603-4b11-8a8d-bcd2157b1309:1 was aborted on statement 0 due to: an error from cluster data placement change :: caused by :: Encountered error from 10.251.245.98:27017 during a transaction :: caused by :: epoch mismatch detected for BESPIN.AwsBillingDaily_1, the collection may have been dropped and recreated" errName:StaleConfig errCode:13388 reslen:716 protocol:op_msg 535ms

Could Anyone give me a clue about what is going on here?

I got one Mongos Router, one Config Servers, and 2 Shards Replica Sets